QUIC connection could not be established
Am running wordpress lightsail instance on Nginx -V 1.25 webserver.
I ran the following commands to install HTTP/3 on Nginx

sudo apt update
2.sudo apt install -y build-essential libpcre3-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.19.0.tar.gz
tar xvf nginx-1.25.tar.gz
git clone --recursive https://github.com/cloudflare/quiche
cd nginx-1.25
patch -p01 < ../quiche/extras/nginx/nginx-1.19.patch

Configured the nginx.conf file with details on image below link:
COnfigurations for nginx.conf file
When i restart nginx to check if the http/3 is enabled i get the error
"HTTP/3 Check could not get establish a QUIC connection due to the error given below.
QUIC connection could not be established" Please help what step or configuration i might have missed.
